# Python3 threading with uWSGI

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, uwsgi, python-multithreading

I wasted many time but couldn't find a solution.
If i use threads in my app deployed with uwsgi, they aren't sync.

Here simple code for an example(wsgi.py):

```
from time import sleep
import threading

i = 0
def daemon():
  global i
  while True:
    i += 1
    print(i)
    sleep(3)
th = threading.Thread(target=daemon, args=())
th.start()

def application(environ, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
  return [str(i).encode()]
```

And when I run this app the `i` increases in log, but I always get `1` when a make request from browser.(Or get `0` if I move `sleep(3)` before `i` first increment)
I tried uwsgi.thread decorator, but got the same result.

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3034
plugins-dir = /srv/uwsgi
plugin = python34
uid = py3utils
gid = py3utils
chdir = /srv/python/3/py3utils/tht/app/
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
enable-threads = true
daemonize = %(chdir)/../uwsgi.log
master = true
die-on-term = true
touch-reload = ../uwsgi_restart.txt
```

*sorry for my English

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens because after importing your application the master process forks into a worker:

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7167)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7169, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 7170)
```

So your thread which prints `i` is running in master process, and your requests are processed by the worker. The worker during the fork sees `i` equal to 1. If you move `sleep` before incrementing `i` the process manages to fork before the first increment.

Threads except the main one are not copied during a fork, so `i` does not increment in the worker.

You should use something like [`uwsgidecorators.thread`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#uwsgidecorators.thread):

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import uwsgidecorators

i = 0

@uwsgidecorators.postfork
@uwsgidecorators.thread
def daemon():
  global i
  while True:
    i += 1
    print(i)
    sleep(3)

def application(environ, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
  return [str(i).encode()]
```

Or use:

```
[uwsgi]
master = false
```

Comment: You saved my sanity. `master = false` enough for my current task.
But a quick question: if I use your code with `@postfork` I got `print` result in log twice for each iteration. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Python threading is disabled by default in uwsgi, you can enable it by adding option `--enable-threads`:

```
uwsgi --http :8090 --wsgi-file uwsgi_test.py --enable-threads
```

It works in my test environment.